# Frames being dropped using AnimationDrawable on Android

Tags: android, performance, android-animation

Here is some animation code I am running on a Nexus 5 Lollipop device :

```
<animation-list
    android:id="@+id/customProgressBar"
    android:oneshot="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_zero" android:duration="250" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_one" android:duration="250" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_two" android:duration="250" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_three" android:duration="250" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_four" android:duration="250" />
</animation-list>
```

The reference drawables are a set of simple rectangles :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <size android:width="70dp"
                android:height="10dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="70dp" android:drawable="@drawable/hollow_square"/>
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="20dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="50dp" android:drawable="@drawable/hollow_square"/>
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="40dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="30dp" android:drawable="@drawable/hollow_square"/>
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="60dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="10dp" android:drawable="@drawable/hollow_square"/>

</layer-list>
```

On testing this piece of code (and nothing else in my content view), I tried the GPU rendering tool on the device. And I see most of the operations take much more than 16 ms - most of the time being shown in ORANGE. From the docs -

> The orange section of the bar represents the time the CPU is waiting
>   for the GPU to finish its work. If this bar gets tall, it means the
>   app is doing too much work on the GPU

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Did anyone else face the same issue ?

Comment: No. I have multiple PNGs

Comment: I presume you never found a solution... any workarounds?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I was trying to make a custom progress indicator, but not using frame animation anymore; there are other approaches to solve that issue.